# How to avoid Windows Hello Face to look for you after locking

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-hello

I have setup Windows Hello Face (WHF) and it works well.
I have GPO Do not display the lock screen policy enabled so that I don't have do anything to get to the desktop when starting my machine.
Here is where WHF works a bit to good.

When I leave my machine I lock Windows with Win-L.
But immediately WHF starts looking for me and almost immediately unlock Windows and show the desktop, here I sort of enter an infinite loop with me pressing Win-L and WHF immediately unlocking....

My question is if there is a way to avoid WHF to look for me directly after locking?
I know that I could revert the GPO but I really don't like to have to dismiss the lock screen every time I logon.
What I would like is for the machine to stay locked until I call upon it by pressing a key or moving the mouse or similar to fire up the camera and start looking for me.